# Eclipse: Is there a way to create dependencies between source folders?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Web Project with two source folders in Eclipse. Folder A, depends on Folder B being compiled. Is there a way to create this dependency in Eclipse, without having to create separate projects for each folder? I know projects can be set up to depend on one another, but I am not looking to do that.

Comment: What do you mean with a folder depends on another folder? The compiler should take care of compiling everything that's needed.

Comment: I mean, Folder A would need Folder B compiled first. Hence, you would not be able to have Folder B reference classes in Folder A.

Comment: _why_ do you need folder B compiled first?

Comment: i'm being dense i guess. what is eclipse not doing for you now?

Comment: @Thorbjorn upvote. it's the unfortunate way that someone configured my companies Web app. The build's scripts actually enforce this, and CI will blow up if it's not the case. I want to change it, but it would be a lot of refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eclipse compiler automatically manages dependencies at the source level within all source folders of a project, you don't have to do anything special.

**Edit:** You answer "you would not be able to have Folder B reference classes in Folder A" to a comment - that's kinda the *opposite* of a dependency. And no, I'm pretty sure you cannot enforce that within a single eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ant task to do that for you

Comment: I know and I have one, but it would be nicer if Eclipse would remind me.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two programs in the same Eclipse project, with two separate main methods. You can then make two separate Run Configurations.

Before running you can then build the project. Building the project will automatically build both programs in the project, so you wont have to remember to manually build your second program.